# When was Zzyzx created in the timeline of the Fablehaven Mullverse?

Tags: fablehaven

I just got on the Fablehaven train a few months ago and basically binge read all the books.

I've been putting together a timeline of events (just for fun) and I'm having a tricky time placing when the creation of Zzyzx actually happened relative to all the other major events in the book.

I'm pretty sure it happened after the First Dragon War and the Creation of Dragonwatch, because during a conversation between Agad and Bracken in DW1 Bracken says to Agad, "You were one of the Founding members of Dragonwatch" to which Agad responds "You know your history." It's kind of a strange exchange because Agad helped with the creation of Zzyzx, which incorporated Bracken's horn as one of the 5 keys, so Bracken and Agad probably met way back then, so I'm assuming they met after the events of Dragonwatch, that or they had no interaction at all at Zzyzx and it was a different wizard who convinced Bracken to part with his horn.

I'm also pretty sure it happened after the creation of the crowns, because the Demon King goes into Zzyzx wearing his crown.

It also happens *before* Graulas uses the Wizenstone to seal off the Source, because Konrad gets sealed off inside there, but he has knowledge of the translocator, unless the Alderfairy told Konrad about the keys because she could see the outside world still...

Mull didn't exactly compile a Silmarillion before writing his books...

Here's my list of significant events thus far:

Where does the creation of Zzyzx most likely fit in here?

1. Giants, the original overlords rule the Earth.
2. Alder Fairy comes through the Source - First of the Fairy folk? (Year?)
3. Source and Void produce the light and dark crowns.
4. Underking happens.
5. Ethergem comes from the Source (Does this happen before or after the
   Alderfairy?) It is given to the Giants.
6. King Titus becomes King of Fairview.
7. Konrad is born.

   - Konrad “kills” Gorgon at age 17, becomes Earl of Farcastle [few
     years pass]
   - Konrad “kills” Yeti, becomes Duke of Hinterhill [‘years’ pass]
   - Konrad “kills” Vampire, marries Princess Lillianna, has two
     daughters (Nadia & Magdalena) and becomes known as The Legender.
     (It’s unknown who came up with the name.) [2-3 years pass]
   - Konrad “kills” the Phoenix, discovers the Source in the desert, and
     meets the Alder Fairy, who encourages him to dip his four talismans
     in the eather (quill, tooth, stake and feather), he also drinks from
     the aether, becoming the first of the Fair Folk.  [1 year later]
   - Konrad is crowned King Konred, Lord Protector of Selona. [Nadia
     turns 17, 13-15 years and two sons later]
   - Dragon King, Kula Bakar challenges Konrad in human form, and kills
     him on the field of battle, but Konrad is resurrected in a blazing
     fire, and kills the Dragon King with his talismans, and claims the
     dragon king’s sword, obtains the title of dragon slayer - No mortal
     Country ever attacks Selona again
   - Konrad passes talismans to sons and daughters, who gained renown as
     dragon slayers.
   - Konrad washes seeds in the Source, and creates the first Fair Folk,
     on the condition that the Fair Folk will defend the balance.
   - Konrad hides the Kingdom of Selona from the rest of the mortal
     world.
8. Founding of Stormguard
9. First Dragon War
10. Founding of Dragon Watch (almost three thousand years ago DW1pg101 - Agad 900BC-ish).
11. Creation of the Dragon Preserves.

    - Founding of Terrabelle
12. Creation of Other Preserves
13. ?Forging of the five Crowns by Graulas and Humbuggle. (Marek is Dormant, so after Dragon War.)

    - Ethergem stolen, Stratos falls.
    - Ethergem Shattered
    - 10 kingdoms of the Fair folk are cursed (Seven Kingdoms of the
      nipsies, Sentient Wood, Walking Stones, Singing Fish) The rest of
      the Fair Folk assume them destroyed or imprisoned.
14. ?Creation of Zzyzx and the fives keys: Sands of Sanctity; Chronometer;
    Translocator; Oculus; and Font of Immortality. (Had to have happened
    after Dragonwatch - Bracken guesses Agad was one of the Founders, to
    which Agad responds, “You know your history” DW1 Bracken and Agad
    met at least when Zzyzx was being sealed, as Bracken gave up his
    horn to make the font of immortality) “Agad nodded pensively. ―The
    former prison lasted for millennia. This new prison will endure far
    longer.” FH5 - Agad
15. ?Formation of Knights of the Dawn.
16. Graulas attempts to use the Wizenstone to seal off the Source. He
    succeeds in sealing it from the mortal world, but the effort almost
    kills him, and he never returns to full power. (this is likely what
    sent his health into decline) The Void is also sealed off as a
    consequence, both are reduced in power. (Happened after creation of Zzyzx: “I have a device called the Translocator.” “I noticed,” Konrad said. “I’m familiar with the device. Mull, Brandon. Dragonwatch, Vol. 5: Return of the Dragon Slayers (p. 464). Shadow Mountain. Kindle Edition.
17. Curse of Stormguard Castle (Humbuggle had to have the wisenstone
    first.)
18. Relocation of Sands of Sanctity

    - Sands of Sanctity brought to America, in modern Day Connecticut.
    - “Europeans” offer to defeat the demon Bahumat in exchange for lands.
    - Bahumat is bound.
    - Fablehaven Preserve established (1711).
19. Patton Burgess - Caretaker of Fablehaven, last member of
    Dragonwatch.
20. Battle at Shoreless Isle, Gates to Zzyzyx
21. Stormguard Curse Broken.
22. Second Dragon War (Declared within a week or two of Seth and Kendra
    becoming caretakers of Wyrmroost.)

    - Font of Immortality unmade (Bracken's third horn acquired with help of Underking.)
    - Wizenstone destroyed
    - Crowns of Giant Queen, Dragon King, and Demon King destroyed.
    - Ethergem Restored